# MojoFailureException | cannot find symbol: com.hazelcast.config.MaxSizeConfig

Tags: java

I'm upgrading my microservice from version 1.5.4 to 2.5.2.

I am having the current issue when building the project. From what I understood, this can happen becouse there is something wrong with the dependencies or sources of a project.
This release spring boot upgrades to Hazelcast 4 whilst keeping compatibility with Hazelcast 3.2.x. If you’re not ready to switch to Hazelcast 4, you can downgrade using the hazelcast.version property in your build. Having our application in version 3.10.2, this library will not be upgraded within the context of this user story.

However, I'm having the following issue:

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/Repo/microservices/eco-microservices/functional/translator-service/src/main/java/com/economical/microservices/translator/config/HazelcastConfiguration.java:[10,28] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class MaxSizeConfig
  location: package com.hazelcast.config
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  45.408 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-08-06T21:46:04+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project translator-service: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /C:/Repo/microservices/eco-microservices/functional/translator-service/src/main/java/com/economical/microservices/translator/config/HazelcastConfiguration.java:[10,28] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class MaxSizeConfig
[ERROR]   location: package com.hazelcast.config
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Follows a pom file snippet:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
         <!-- Spring Framework Caching Support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
            <artifactId>hazelcast</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
            <artifactId>hazelcast-spring</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSON Libraries -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Data JPA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Can you please help me understand what the issue is?

Answer (score 1):

You are not defining what version of the dependencies you are using. In the latest version of Hazelcast there seems not to be any `MaxSizeConfig` class any longer.